# node.js / express application - where do i put the database connection logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, redis, node-redis

**Background Information**

I just created my first express application. I can see that it created a bunch of files and default folder structure.  This is what my app structure currently looks like:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1$ ls -lah
total 36K
drwxr-xr-x  7 me me 4.0K Sep 28 09:26 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me 4.0K Sep 28 08:45 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1.5K Sep 28 08:45 app.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4.0K Sep 28 09:20 bin
drwxrwxr-x 96 me me 4.0K Sep 28 09:26 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me  352 Sep 28 09:26 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me 4.0K Sep 28 08:45 public
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4.0K Sep 28 09:26 routes
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4.0K Sep 28 08:45 views
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1$
```

**Goal**

I want to create a new route called 'widgets' and when the GET method is invoked, I need to call a redis database and execute a query. 
The URL I want to use to trigger this get is something like this:

```
  http://myserver/tutorial1/widgets/
```

or

```
  http://myserver/tutorial1/widgets/12345
```

where 12345 is the widget key that I want to query.

**What I've done so far**

I found this doc that explains how to connect / query a redis database: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#redis

I've also copied routes/users.js that the express generator created "for free" for me to routes/widgets.js as a starting point.

This is what my routes/widgets.js file looks like:

```
me@mydev:/var/www/html/nodejs_samples/tutorial1$ cat routes/widgets.js 
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET widgets listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Question**

It's not clear to me where I should add the database connection logic and the query logic.  I'm used to MVC where you split all database logic into the model.

Can I put everything in the route/widgets.js file?

In case it helps, here's a link to what my app.js file looks like:  http://pastebin.com/hAe5mvwt.  I added 2 lines - line 10 and 28.

Any suggestions or links to good tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: You *could*, but then it's coupled directly to the route handler. It's fine to start out that way, but I prefer a stronger separation of concerns. Ultimately this boils down to opinion: there's no one specific "right" way to break up functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, MVC works well and database stuff can certainly go into the model.

But, there are lots of ways to skin a cat.  With something rather trivial at this point, I think you should do what is convenient for you and feels like a reasonably clean design.

The issue is that as your system grows more complex, you need a way to evolve it smoothly.  You are never going to have the final ultimate 'best' design because realities change as you go.

Be sure to look at node-modules.com, npmjs.com, npms.io first to explore the many (and quite varied) powerful designs already implemented and popular.

I think you should explore, if you have time, multiple different strategies for organizing your code.

The bigger issue though is, how can you possibly change this design down the road (you *will* want to change it eventually) without completely breaking your application (and not knowing it)?

So I think rather than agonizing over the code organization too much now, spend that effort in coming up with ways to automatically test as much of it as possible.  That way when you change the design, you will be able to see what broke -- and it will therefore be feasible to change the design.

You want unit tests where practical, otherwise integration tests, larger case end-to-end tests.

If you can put something into its own module/model file/whatever and test it separately as a unit then that is better than other designs probably.

Comment: I like your suggestion, a lot.  Separating code into testable units is a good overall principle for me to keep in mind.  I guess what i will do is start by putting everything into the specific routes file... just to learn node and express... and then once I'm familiar with it... maybe put on the testing hat and revisit my sample code to see what kind of refactoring would best support testing.